# Understanding Abstract Factory Design pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns

in Abstract Factory design pattern , a class delegates the responsibility of object instantiation to another object via composition.

can some one explain it with some example.

Comment: Are you referring to abstract classes, or the Abstract Factory pattern?

Comment: abstract factory pattern

Comment: @OP: are you familiar with the Simple Factory Pattern? Abstract factory is (more or less) a Simple Factory that generates a Simple Factory that can generate concrete classes :)

Comment: tht what i want to understood in abstract factory pattern : a class delegates the responsibility of object instantiation to another object via composition. while in Factory pattern uses inheritance and relies on a subclass to handle the object instantiation. what u all explaining here is that both abstract factory and factory using inheritance, then where is the difference in both the pattern . @Sweko : difference is one more layer of abstraction.

Comment: As per understanding about Abstract factory is it Abstract Factory pattern is used when you have factories that can create a family of objects. while there is abstraction of Factory class.

while in case of factory method have abstraction over factory class and it produces single set of product objects. that's my understanding over factory method pattern and abstract factory pattern. let me know if i m wrong. while my query is over the composition and inheritance one.

Answer (score 5):

I'll tell you a traditional example about that. Imagine you have a UI library. It have implementation of different UI components like buttons, sliders, radio buttons, etc. You also want to have different look-and-feel of these components, for example silver, dark, light, windows-like, gtk-like etc. You can use an abstract class which makes the common things for each component's creation and child classes which inherit from the abstract and specifies only the differences:

```
class AbstractComponentFactory {

    public abstract Button createButton() {
        //implementation
    }

    public abstract Slider createSlider() {
        //implementation
    }
}

class SilverComponentFactory extends AbstractFactory {

    public Button createButton() {
        Button b = base.createButton();
        //customize the button
    }

    public Slider createSlider() {
        Slider b = base.createSlider();
        //customize the slider
    }

}


class WindowsComponentFactory extends AbstractFactory {

    public Button createButton() {
        Button b = base.createButton();
        //customize the button with windows look-and-feel
    }

    public Slider createSlider() {
        Slider b = base.createSlider();
        //customize the slider with windows look-and-feel
    }

}
```

Now if you need to create components you can change dynamically the implementation of the Abstract factory:

```
public void createUI(AbstractComponentFactory f) {
     Button b = f.createButton();
     Slider s = f.createSlider();
}

//..
createUI(new SilverComponentFactory());
```

[Here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a7/Abstract_factory.svg) is a sample class diagram, I hope it's not so complex.